# Same Library file working on stm32f7 but not on stm32f4

Tags: c, i2c, stm32f4, stm32f7

I am stuck with a really weird issue while using time of flight sensor `VL53L0x - 200 cm` and `VL6180x - 60 cm`. I have two st boards, `STM32F446 Nucleo` and `STM32F767 Nucleo`. I have written the libraries for both the time of flight sensors on  `STM32F767 Nucleo`. But while i was trying to implement the same library on `STM32F446 Nucleo` it doesn't work.

While looking for solution i found there is a problem with I2C. In F7 everything is fine and it returns HAL_OK. But in F4 it returns 'HAL_ERROR'. By *it*  I mean this function.

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint16_t DevAddress, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout)
```

Pastebin link for library files

https://pastebin.com/z15btwTD - vl6180.c

https://pastebin.com/62XYxUVx - vl6180.h

Ofcourse in `vl6180.h` i have changed `#include "stm32f7xx.h"` to `#include "stm32f4xx.h"` while using for `STM32F446 Nucleo`. And i am using I2C1 in both the boards. But i have tried other I2C's too but they all end up in same problem. Hal library is generated using CubeMx and Attolic True Studio is the IDE.

The same thing is happening for `VL53L0X Sensor`.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

**EDIT**

From this particular part of the `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit()` function returns `HAL_ERROR`

```
if(I2C_MasterRequestWrite(hi2c, DevAddress, Timeout, tickstart) != HAL_OK)
{
  if(hi2c->ErrorCode == HAL_I2C_ERROR_AF)
  {
    /* Process Unlocked */
    __HAL_UNLOCK(hi2c);
    //HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(BLUE_GPIO_Port, BLUE_Pin);
    return HAL_ERROR;
  }
  else
  {
    /* Process Unlocked */
    __HAL_UNLOCK(hi2c);
    return HAL_TIMEOUT;
  }
}
```

Regards.

Comment: usually such issues are wrong i2c address, though how about tracing through HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit and seeing exactly where the problem lies?

Comment: I have traced the exact location of HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit and Edited the question please check.

Comment: Are the pin muxes configured correctly for I2C? Do the pins need external pull-up resistors, and if so, are they fitted?

Comment: Yes external pull-up is fitted. What do u meant by pin muxes for i2c?

Comment: Have you traced why `I2C_MasterRequestWrite` returns something other than `HAL_OK`?